# При сравнении двух одинаковых массивов выдает false

Tags: c#

У меня есть два массива, которые я должен сравнить. При использовании обычного сравнения через `==` выдает `false`. Использовал всевозможные проверки - все они показали, что элементы массивов одинаковы.
Не могу понять почему при сравнении получаю такой результат.

```
int[] a = new[] { 965, 644, 427, 537, 476, 250, 430, 307, 702, 485, 796, 729, 949, 992, 442, 515, 436, 966, 633, 790, 942, 169, 413, 903, 947, 748, 458, 400, 387, 247, 968, 627, 917, 695, 475, 81, 873, 455, 757, 321, 308, 635, 938, 247, 103, 56, 843, 619, 957, 257, 483, 974, 958, 304, 573, 435, 830, 890, 717, 285, 995, 793, 850, 544 };
```

```
int[] b = new[] { 965, 644, 427, 537, 476, 250, 430, 307, 702, 485, 796, 729, 949, 992, 442, 515, 436, 966, 633, 790, 942, 169, 413, 903, 947, 748, 458, 400, 387, 247, 968, 627, 917, 695, 475, 81, 873, 455, 757, 321, 308, 635, 938, 247, 103, 56, 843, 619, 957, 257, 483, 974, 958, 304, 573, 435, 830, 890, 717, 285, 995, 793, 850, 544 };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Массив использует сравнение из базового класса, а базовым классом массива является object. Суть этого сравнения в том, что сравниваются ссылки на объект а не содержимое массивов.
Для сравнения содержимого используйте [SequenceEqual](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?view=net-6.0).